# How to redraw jQuery DataTable after link is clicked without navigating from page?

Tags: javascript, c#, jquery, href, url.action

I have a column in my jQuery datatable that renders a green checkmark link if data == true or a red X if data == false:

```
{
    data: "HasPayment",
    render: function (data, type, row) {
        var paymentSet = '@Url.Action("Set", "Payment")?applicationId=' + row.Id + '&year=' + row.Year + '&month=' + row.Month + '&hasPayment=' + data;
        if (data) {
            return '<a href=\"' + paymentSet + '\" class="fas fa-solid fa-check" style="color: green"></a>';
        }
        return '<a href=\"' + paymentSet + '\" class="fas fa-solid fa-times" style="color: red"></a>';
    }
},
```

The problem is that when I click one of the links (either green checkmark or red X), it navigates to another page. I know that this is because I am using `href` and `Url.Action`.

When a user clicks one of the links, I want to call the `/Payment/Set` method to update the data (green checkmark to red X and vice versa) and then I want to redraw my datatable (i.e. `dataTable.draw()`) without navigating from the current page (i.e. Index view). `/Payment/Set` method updates the data without returning anything (i.e. void).

**Update**: I tried the following and it almost works, meaning that when I click one of the links, the data is updated and the datatable is refreshed, except it still tries to navigate to another page.

```
{
    data: "HasPayment",
    render: function (data, type, row) {
        var paymentSet = '@Url.Action("Set", "Payment")?applicationId=' + row.Id + '&year=' + row.Year + '&month=' + row.Month + '&hasPayment=' + data;
        if (data) {
            return '<a href=\"' + paymentSet + '\" onclick="return onclickFunction()" class="fas fa-solid fa-check" style="color: green"></a>';
        }
        return '<a href=\"' + paymentSet + '\" onclick="return onclickFunction()" class="fas fa-solid fa-times" style="color: red"></a>';
    }
},


<script>
    function onclickFunction() {
        $.ajax({
            type: "GET",
            url: $(this).attr("href"),
            success: function () {
                paymentDataTable.ajax.reload();
            }
        });
    }
</script>
```

Comment: You should not use the anchor tag, <a> which is used to navigate to other pages. You should use a button and an onclick event callback.
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/a?retiredLocale=it

Answer (score 0):

If you use an anchor `<a>` it is obvious that the browser will navigate to another page. That's the actual purpose of the anchor tag.

You should use an AJAX function to call when your button is pressed and at the callback call the reload of the table.

This can be a way:

```
{
    data: "HasPayment",
    render: function (data, type, row) {            
        if (data) {
            return '<button class="fas fa-solid fa-check" style="color: green" onclick="setPayment(row.Id, row.Year, row.Month, data)"></button>';
        }
        return '<button class="fas fa-solid fa-times" style="color: red" onclick="doSomethingElseMaybe()"></button>';
    }
}
```

Then you should create two more functions, one with the AJAX call and one with the table reload to be called as callback.

```
function setPayment(id, month, year, data){
var url = `Payment/Set?applicationId=${id}&year=${year}&month=${month}&hasPayment=${data}`;
$.ajax({
    type: "POST", //OR GET? it depends on your backend
    url: url,
    contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
    dataType: "json",
    success: function (result) {
        reloadTable();
    },
    error: () => {
        console.error("500 Internal Server Error.");}
});
}
```

Then in the reloadTable function just call the ajax.reload() method of the DataTable api.

for example

```
function reloadTable(){
datatable.ajax.reload();
}
```

Here is the [documentation](https://datatables.net/reference/api/ajax.reload()) of DataTables reload method.

Here is the [documentation](https://api.jquery.com/jquery.ajax/) of JQuery AJAX.

You may have to adapt the example code to your specific backend purpose.

Comment: I have tried this, even simpler examples, such as just trying to display a console message, but clicking one of the buttons just refreshes the entire webpage without updating the data (i.e. green checkmark to red X and vice versa), which I assume means that the method is not being called.

Comment: Check if the URL is correct, if it's the case remove the initial '/' from the string. 
Do you have any error in the browser console?

Comment: the url is correct, I have even tried the absolute path, but no luck. I do not have an error in the browser console.

Comment: try changing the <a> with a button tag, remove the href and build your url inside the JS function.